# How to delete firefox cookies in C#?

Tags: firefox, cookies, delete-file

I delete firefox cookies by this code:

```
if(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cookies.sqlite")
{
File.Delete(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cookies.sqlite");
}
```

but when I run firefox, deleted file restored again.

Can one help me?

Answer (score -1):

Why you dont use "DELETE" sql command insted of deleting sql file? You can use sqlite file in your C# application.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx

[http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/)